# DynamoDB - Object to AttributeValue

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm aware of DynamoDBMapper but in my case I can't use it because I don't know all the attributes beforehand.

I have a JSON and it's parsed to a map of objects by using `Jackson` parser:

```
Map<String, Object> userData = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), Map.class);
```

Looping through each attribute, how can I convert the value to `AttributeValue` given that DynamoDB `AttributeValue` supports Boolean, String, Number, Bytes, List, etc.

Is there an efficient way to do this? Is there a library for this already? My naive approach is to check if each value is of type Boolean/String/Number/etc. and then call the appropriate `AttributeValue` method, e.g: `new AttributeValue().withN(value.toString())` - which gives me long lines of `if, else if`

Comment: I have a similar use case. How do you do the opposite - convert Map<String,AttributeValue> to an Item? I have streams enabled but the DynamoDBKinesisStreamsAdapter returns a Map<String,AttributeValue> ... see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.Walkthrough.html .. I want to convert the AttributeValue to Object (Item returns a Map<String,Object> on .asMap)

Comment: @shrewquest Did you have any luck in finding a solution?

Comment: @shrewquest Item.fromMap( InternalUtils.toSimpleMapValue( mapOfAttributes ) )

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Finally figured out by looking at how [AWS parses the JSON](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/c19606a6a5bfcc0e8cc7d33dde5e4f20425ca33e/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.java#L908)

Basically, this is the code:

```
    Item item = new Item().withJSON("document", jsonStr);
    Map<String,AttributeValue> attributes = InternalUtils.toAttributeValues(item);
    return attributes.get("document").getM();
```

Very neat.

Comment: how I can convert from `Map<String,AttributeValue>` to Object ?

Comment: This is a fantastic find. Thank you.

Comment: @BohdanKorinnyi The approach taken by @BPm also has a method for converting the `Map<String,AttributeValue>` to `List<Item>`, which would allow you to then have access to the actual primitive types (e.g. like `item.getBoolean(attrName)`). If that fits your use-case, then see: [toItemList](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/internal/InternalUtils.java#L49)

Comment: The `InternalUtils` class is deprecated (use [ItemUtils](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/ItemUtils.html) instead).

Comment: This method doesn't work if the source Object has a ByteBuffer field.

Json converts it into struct and AttributeValue considers it to be a Map.

Comment: @GPcyborg yes. How can use overcome when we have ByteBuffer fields ?

Answer (score 6):

Following is a simple solution which can be applied to convert any DynamoDB Json to Simple JSON.

```
//passing the reponse.getItems() 
public static Object getJson(List<Map<String,AttributeValue>> mapList) {
    List<Object> finalJson= new ArrayList();
    for(Map<String,AttributeValue> eachEntry : mapList) {
        finalJson.add(mapToJson(eachEntry));
    }
    return finalJson;
}


//if the map is null then it add the key and value(string) in the finalKeyValueMap
public static Map<String,Object> mapToJson(Map<String,AttributeValue> keyValueMap){
    Map<String,Object> finalKeyValueMap = new HashMap();
    for(Map.Entry<String, AttributeValue> entry : keyValueMap.entrySet()) 
    {
        if(entry.getValue().getM() == null) {
            finalKeyValueMap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().getS());
        }
        else {
            finalKeyValueMap.put(entry.getKey(),mapToJson(entry.getValue().getM()));
        }
    }
    return finalKeyValueMap;
}
```

This will produce your desired Json in the form of `List<Map<String,Object>>` which is subset of the `object`.

Comment: this code only convert values which is of string type not other types like numbers etc.

Comment: can you update your code to work for all types values ?

Answer (score 6):

I used [JacksonConverterImpl](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-mars-json-demo/blob/master/ingester/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/json/converter/impl/JacksonConverterImpl.java) to convert `JsonNode` to `Map<String, AttributeValue>`

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class);
final JacksonConverter converter = new JacksonConverterImpl();
Map<String, AttributeValue> map = converter.jsonObjectToMap(jsonNode);
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 2):

With the 2.x SDK, I have not yet identified an equivalent provided by the SDK. As an exercise I decided to solve this with switch expressions

This implementation will marshal maps, records, primitives, byte arrays, collection types and will call `toString()` on unknown types. The only datatype I did not implement was a byte set (BS) as it's not as trivial to determine unique byte array values.

You could add support for bean properties, but I figured it would be error prone and decided to just support `toString` in default.

Have included `unmarshal` as an exercise also.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;


public class AttributeValueConverter {

    public static AttributeValue fromCollection(Collection<? extends Object> c) {
        if (c instanceof Set s && s.stream().allMatch(n -> n instanceof String)) {
            var vals = c.stream()
                .map(n -> (String) n)
                .collect(toList());
            return AttributeValue.fromSs(vals);
        }
        var vals = c.stream()
            .map(x -> marshal(x))
            .collect(toList());
        return AttributeValue.fromL(vals);
    }

    public static AttributeValue fromMap(Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> m) {
        var vals = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        m.forEach((k, v) ->
            vals.put(k.toString(), marshal(v))
        );
        return AttributeValue.fromM(vals);
    }

    public static AttributeValue fromRecord(Record r) {
        var vals = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        var components = r.getClass().getRecordComponents();
        for (var component : components) {
            try {
                vals.put(
                    component.getName(),
                    marshal(component.getAccessor().invoke(r))
                );
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                // will happen if the class is not accessible
            }
        }
        return AttributeValue.fromM(vals);
    }

    public static AttributeValue marshal(Object obj) {
        return switch (obj) {
            case null           -> AttributeValue.fromNul(true);
            case Optional opt   -> opt.isPresent()
                                   ? marshal(opt.get())
                                   : AttributeValue.fromNul(true);
            case Boolean b      -> AttributeValue.fromBool(b);
            case Number n       -> AttributeValue.fromN(n.toString());
            case String s       -> AttributeValue.fromS(s);
            // string representations of temporals are mostly what you want
            //case Temporal t     -> AttributeValue.fromS(t.toString());
            case Collection c   -> fromCollection(c);
            case Map m          -> fromMap(m);
            case Record r       -> fromRecord(r);
            case Object o when o.getClass().isArray() -> {
                var ctype = obj.getClass().getComponentType().getTypeName();
                if ("byte".equals(ctype)) {
                    yield AttributeValue.fromB(
                        SdkBytes.fromByteArray((byte[]) obj)
                    );
                }
                yield fromCollection(Arrays.asList((Object[]) obj));
            }
            default -> AttributeValue.fromS(obj.toString());
        };
    }

    private static final Pattern INT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^-?[0-9]+$");

    private static Number parseNumber(String n) {
        if (INT_PATTERN.matcher(n).matches()) {
            if (n.length() < 10) {
                return Integer.valueOf(n);
            }
            return Long.valueOf(n);
        }
        return Double.valueOf(n);
    }

    public static Object unmarshal(AttributeValue av) {
        return switch (av.type()) {
            case B      -> av.b().asByteArray();
            case BOOL   -> av.bool();
            case BS     -> av.bs().stream()
                            .map(SdkBytes::asByteArray)
                            .collect(toList());
            case L      -> av.l().stream()
                            .map(AttributeValueConverter::unmarshal)
                            .collect(toList());
            case M      -> av.m().entrySet().stream()
                            .collect(toMap(
                                Entry::getKey,
                                n -> Optional.ofNullable(unmarshal(n.getValue()))
                            ));
            case N      -> parseNumber(av.n());
            case NS     -> av.ns().stream()
                            .map(AttributeValueConverter::parseNumber)
                            .collect(toSet());
            case NUL    -> null;
            case S      -> av.s();
            case SS     -> Set.copyOf(av.ss());
            case UNKNOWN_TO_SDK_VERSION ->
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Type not supported");
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Its absolutely insane there is not an equivalent for the 2.x SDK.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2.x SDK, use `DynamoDBEnhancedClient`.

```
DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
     .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
     .build();
DynamoDbTable<Customer> custTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));
Customer record = new Customer();
            record.setCustName("Fred Pink");
            record.setId("id110");
            record.setEmail("fredp@noserver.com");
// Put the customer data into an Amazon DynamoDB table.
custTable.putItem(record);
```

Here is a full example:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/enhanced/EnhancedPutItem.java

Answer (score 0):

If you have an annotated bean (@DynamoDbBean) and just want to convert a POJO, I found this:

M bean = ....;
TableSchema tableSchema = (TableSchema)TableSchema.fromClass(bean.getClass());
Map<String, software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue> itemMap = tableSchema.itemToMap(bean, true);