# Convert JSON string to DynamoDB LastEvaluatedKey

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb, gson

I have tried using Gson

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = gson.fromJson(paginationTokenString, new TypeToken<Map<String, AttributeValue>>() { }.getType());
```

For the JSON string

```json
{
  "createdBy": {
    "S": "1234567"
  },
  "caseCreationDateTime": {
    "S": "2022-05-02T10:38:16.574590Z"
  },
  "caseId": {
    "S": "534kjnsjf"
  }
}
```

I'm getting the output something like this `{createdBy={}, caseCreationDateTime={}, caseId={}}`

Is there any other way to convert JSON String to `Map<String, AttributeValue>`?

Comment: If `AttributeValue` is what is described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html , then you need to implement a custom deserializer for this type.

Comment: Probably closely related to, or a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27500749